# gdal_translate error when cropping sentinel 1 image

Tags: r, gdal, sentinel

I downloaded a Sentinel1 product from the esa open acces hub. In the downloaded directory is a tif-file containing the measurement data. I would now like to crop this tif-file to the window that I need.

For this I use the gdal_translate function in R

```
     gdal_translate( 'from.tiff', to.tiff , projwin = c( 4.5, 52.4, 4.7,    52.2 ))
```

This returns an error

```
ERROR 1: Error: Computed -srcwin 4.5 52 0 0 has negative width and/or height.
```

I figured it might be a coordinate reference frame problem, but when I open the file in qgis it shows nice wgs84.

When I read in the file using

```
raster('from.tiff')
```

I notice that the raster extent is just the pixel dimensions. (As opposed to when I open it in Qgis)

How can I crop this 'from.tiff' file to the desired extent?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have mixed up your minimum and maximum latitude. The correct command would be:

```
gdal_translate( 'from.tiff', to.tiff , projwin = c( 4.5, 52.2, 4.7, 52.4 ))
```

Comment: The documentation asks for the order c(ulx,uly,lrx,lry).